# Setting the icon for my App?

Tags: ios, xcode6, icons

![I'm trying to submit my app to Appstore but I'm facing a problem with setting up the icon for my app, I've tried all the variation of sizes for the icon size, but still it's giving me errors , I have taken a snapshot for those errors please help :]

[image: error snapshot]

Comment: from the error it is showing your icon image size is not matching crete icon image according to size shown in warning

Answer (score 0):

Take 1024x1024 icon and generate other icons form http://makeappicon.com/

Answer (score 0):

The images you use should be exactly in the specified dimensions. Even when you can put them "inside the box" of the UI, they must be correctly sized. Please check your files in the Editor, if they are really the right size.

And then, also try with clean build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the icons (`Icon-*`) from `Images.xcassets`, you don't need them there. You just need to drag your icons from Finder into their respective boxes inside `AppIcon`. And make sure you have the correct size for each icon.

Comment: It's fixed that thanks, but really strange, I don't understand why apple didn't add the sizes of the images on the icon squares in the Appicon !

Comment: You're getting "Ambiguous Content" warnings because Xcode doesn't know which of the same size icon to use. Xcode makes a copy of your image into `Images.xcassets/AppIcon/<file_name>` when you already have another version of it in `Images.xcassets`.

Also, if this fixed your problem. Would you mind accepting it. :) Cheers!